# status 415 angular+mysql

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, formularios, spring-boot

tengo un problema. Estoy haciendo la conexion a la base de datos de mysql y tengo un form que me quisiera que envie una serie de datos junto con un comentario a la BD, el problema es que al momento de enviar el POST me retiorna un status 415 "Content type'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported". Probe variar soluciones y nada. Ademas al momento de agregar el metodo al TS del componente me da error y nose si tiene relacion

**Este es el TS del componente**

```html
import { usuarios } from './../../model/Usuario';
import { PorfolioService } from 'src/app/servicies/porfolio.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-comments',
  templateUrl: './comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comments.component.css']
})
export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {

  usuario:usuarios = new usuarios();

  constructor(private router:Router, private service:PorfolioService)  { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  Guardar(){
    this.service.createUsuario(this.usuario)
    .subscribe(data=>{
      alert("Se envio su mensaje con exito!");
      this.router.navigate(["Inicio/Comentarios"]);
    })
  }

}
```

**Este es el formulario**

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Deja tu comentario</h1>
            <form style="margin: 5rem;" >
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputNombre">Nombre</label>
                                <input [(ngModel)]="usuario.nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nombre">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                                <input [(ngModel)]="usuario.mail" name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputAddress">Empresa</label>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="usuario.empresa" name="empresa" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Empresa">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="comment">Comentarios</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment"
                                placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button (click)="Guardar()" style="margin: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Este es el servicio**

```html
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { usuarios } from '../model/Usuario';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {


  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  Url='http://localhost:8080/databases/usuarios';

  getUsuario(){
    return this.http.get<usuarios[]>(this.Url);
  }
  createUsuario(){
    return this.http.post<usuarios>(this.Url,usuarios);
  }

  obtenerDatos():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
  }

}
```

**El error lo da en this.usuario**
`Guardar(){this.service.createUsuario(this.usuario)`
**En terminal**
*Se esperaban 0 argumentos, pero se obtuvieron 1.*

Deberia agregar algo para saltar el status 415?
*ACTUALIZO el problema radicaria en el front ya que con postman me da status 200 sin problemas

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Agrega el código de `createUsuario`

Comment: Se me olvido jaja

Comment: El método `createUsuario` no tiene declarado ningún parámetro. De ahí el error de consola.

Comment: si me di cuenta pero lo agrego y me sigue dando status 415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo que NO tienes acceso a la API y que solo es problema del frontend, asumo esto porque tu pregunta no menciona ni hace referencia a ello.

Vamos por partes:

```
this.service.createUsuario(this.usuario) // En tu servicio, estás enviando 1 parámetro.
```

Y en el código hay:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { usuarios } from '../model/Usuario';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {


  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { }

  Url='http://localhost:8080/databases/usuarios';

  getUsuario(){
    return this.http.get<usuarios[]>(this.Url);
  }
  createUsuario(){ // Aquí estás recibiendo 0 parámetros
    return this.http.post<usuarios>(this.Url,usuarios); // ¿de dónde salió "usuarios"? ¿No te pinta error?
  }

  obtenerDatos():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json');
  }

}
```

Solución:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; // 1. La importación

createUsuario(usuarios: any) :Observable<any> { // 2. Aquí estás recibiendo 1 parámetro y retornas un Observable.
    // 3. Define los Headers:
    const headers= new HttpHeaders()
   .set('content-type', 'application/json');
    // 4. Incluye el header creado en el punto anterior.
        return this.http.post<usuarios>(this.Url,usuarios, { headers:headers }); 
      }
```